# Why does the newborn acknowledge Ripley as its mother?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-resurrection-1997

I never understood the whole Queen/Ripley reproductive process. In *Alien: Resurrection*, the newborn brutally kills the Queen after she gives birth to it. Surprisingly, it has human characteristics. Why does it acknowledge Ripley as its mum if the Queen gave birth to it?

Comment: I'm sure there are *reasons*, but ultimately the real reason is that Resurrection sucks ;)

Answer (score 8):

The [novelisation](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_Resurrection_(novel)) strongly indicates that it's because the newborn feels a greater psychic connection to Ripley than the Alien Queen. It recognised Ripley as the Queen and the Alien Queen simply as a threat and potential food source:

> *That was when the telepathic connection slithered through, touching
>   her [Ripley's] mind, whispering to her of genetic bonds she could not deny. And
>   then it was all right there. Her longing for the steaming warmth of
>   the crèche, the strength and safety of her own kind. Just a moment
>   before she had suffered the aloneness of her own individuality. But
>   now she was given the chance, again, too in them, rejoice with them.
>   She was in the crèche. She could reunite with the warriors, and serve
>   as the Queen, nurturer of the Newborn. That was why she had lived.
>   Because this shell that was human, this Ripley, was the mother of them
>   all. The first womb. The first warrior. And she had lived long enough
>   to know it all, to share the glory with them. **Ripley was the keystone
>   of the hive. The nurturer of the crèche. The foundation of the
>   Newborn.This was the answer to the question she'd been asking. Why?
>   This was why.***
>
> *She gazed into the liquid brown eyes that could have
>   been her own, and reached out a hand, placing it on the Newborn's
>   skull. Her hand slid over the long, Alien head, patting it as she once
>   had done to Amy's, stroking it as she once had done to Newt. This was
>   her child, just as they were.The Newborn uttered a soft mewling sound,
>   and gazed at her, and Ripley felt the telepathic connection deepen,
>   grow stronger. It was so different from the others, yet the same. But
>   there was something more in this contact, something undeniably human.*
>
> *It was like being connected to a part of herself, a warped, malevolent
>   part that was bonded to all her fierce self-preservation, all her
>   intense determination.*